# Use Dependency Injection outside Controller asp.net-core v1.1.0 for application settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp.net-core v1.1.0 :)

I want to access the application settings values from a service class and not from a controller, my code is:

appsettings.json

```
// appsettings.json
{
  "ImagesDBSettings": {
    "Endpoint": "",
    "Key": "",
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
// Startup.cs
...
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<ImagesDBSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ImagesDBSettings"));
    ...
}
...
```

ImagesDBSettings.cs

```
// ImagesDBSettings.cs
public class ImagesDBSettings
{
    public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

ImagesDBService.cs

```
// ImagesDBService.cs
public class ImagesDBService
{
    private readonly ImagesDBSettings _settings;
    public ImagesDBService(IOptions<ImagesDBSettings> settings)
    {
        _settings = settings.Value;
    }
}
```

On compiling I get the error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'settings' of 'ImagesDBService.ImagesDBService(IOptions)'

Any ideas on how to make the Dependency Injection Work?

Comment: do you have any types derived from `ImagesDBService`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IOptions dependancy will not be injected into the ImagesDBService with the code shown. You need to use AddTransient in startup.cs for that. For the DI outside controller see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189984/dependency-injection-with-classes-other-than-a-controller-class). Or you can pass IOptions to your service class from the controller (not the best option).

```
public IActionResult Index(IOptions<ImagesDBSettings> settings)
{
    ImagesDBService ss = new ImagesDBService(settings);
    return View();
}
```

Here is how I do it in my app without the DI. I have a static AppSettings class that I configure in ConfigureServices (startup.cs). I then simply have access to my AppSettings anywhere in the app.

```
public static class AppSettings
{
    public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }        
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    AppSettings.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
}
```

Comment: At the end, I just gave up, the transient option still required to use the controller, what I was looking for (not explained in the question) was to access the Configuration file from a Class independent of any controller or Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

You said it's a **compiling** error so probably not something to do with DI, it's more likely you are missing the `IOptions<>` namespace.

If you haven't done it already, install package: [Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions from Nuget.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/)

Then reference the namespace `Microsoft​.Extensions​.Options` to your class `ImagesDBService`

Comment: The class already contains `using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;` :(

Comment: Is there any more code, or what you posted is the exact shape of your class? Does it inherit from some other class?

Comment: Did you mean "on execution" instead of "on compiling"?

Comment: Thanks for your help Klinger, is on compiling, on vscode I execute the "run" command and on the compiling step the compiler throws that error. ImagesDBServices doesn't inherit from another class.

Comment: The only additional thing I can think of is that you are missing a reference.