# DotNet Core , No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I want to select data from my table "Header" using a simple LINQ command but I faced error.

**My Action**

```
    public HeaderModel GetHeaderInformation()
    {
        using(var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var header = context.Headers.Select(x => new HeaderModel
            {
                colorCode = x.colorCode,
                height = x.height,
                Id = x.Id,
                left = x.left,
                top = x.top,
                width = x.width
            }).FirstOrDefault();

            return header;
        }
    }
```

**The Error**

> Additional information: No database provider has been configured for
>   this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the
>   DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the
>   application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also
>   ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in
>   its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

**My ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> 
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public ApplicationDbContext() : base() { }

    public DbSet<Header> Headers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
}
```

**My Startup.cs**

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddMvc();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using dependency injection. `services.AddDbContext` is in charge of creating you an DbContext object.
There is no point in having that using block because, by doing that, you are instancing a new ApplicationDbContext that doesn't have a connection string.

Write your method like this:

```
public HeaderModel GetHeaderInformation(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    // the code inside your using block
}
```

and .Net will resolve the context via dependency injection.

Furthermore, a common practice is to have the DbContext as a private readonly atribute in your constructor class. So you may want do something like this:

```
public class MyConroller : Controller
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public MyConroller(MyDbContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }
}
```

and just use the context atribute in your methods.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just want to new my dbContext in the using block and use its DbSet<> to select , add and delete data. your solution is fine but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: How can I have the dbcontext injected into the contructors of classes that arent controllers?

Comment: @zuckerthoben you have the answer for that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189984/dependency-injection-with-classes-other-than-a-controller-class) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your parameterless constructor, because it is probably the one that is being called when a new instance is created by the DI. I know that for some people this was the problem, I hope it helps.