# How to correctly get dependent scoped services from ISecurityTokenValidator

Tags: asp.net-core

In my asp.net core 2.0 web app, I've got a custom `ISecurityTokenValidator` which validates tokens.

It depends on a repository to do a db lookup - the repository itself is setup as a scoped dependency:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyRepository>(MyRepository);
```

Now the funkiness comes about because of the way the ISecurityTokenValidator is setup.

It's added in `ConfigureServices`:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new MyTokenValidator(services.BuildServiceProvider()));
    })
```

This is how it looks:

```
public class MyTokenValidator : ISecurityTokenValidator
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public MyTokenValidator(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public bool CanReadToken(string securityToken) => true;

    public ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters,
        out SecurityToken validatedToken)
    {

        var serviceScopeFactory = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var myRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyRepository>();
            var principalFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>>();

            // Use the repo....

        }

    }
}
```

Now, because the `IsecurityTokenProvider` is only instantiated once, it's effectively a singleton. When I use the service provider to ask for a `IMyRepository` I was finding that I was always received the same object - there is no new scope as far as it was concerned, because it's in a singleton class.

To get round that, you'll see in the code above Ive had to manually force a new scope every time the token validator is called. Is this really the only way to resolve this, it seems like I'm hacking around to make it work here...

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, trying to retrieve the `UserManager` in a token validator.

Comment: I ended up refactoring all this away - I didn't need to hang off jwt Auth, so I created my own "API key" Auth middleware

Comment: What do you mean you didn't need to hang off jwt Auth? In my case, I am trying to authorize using JWT tokens issued by Google OAuth from the client side. So it seems I need to wire up my own Google JWT token validator class that inherits from `ISecurityTokenValidator` and implementes `ValidateToken`, where I can then delegate all the token validation to a method in a class provided by google: `Google.Apis.Auth.GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync`

Comment: I was using `.AddJwtToken` but I was using my own ISecurityTokenValidator which didn't actually need to do anything with JWT Tokens. So I ripped it all out, and replaced with my own `AuthenticationHandler` (probs not applicable to your scenario)

Comment: ah I see. I explained my need and approach here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727900/google-jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-0/48768183#48768183

Answer (score 26):

Old question but the best way I have found to solve this problem is to use `IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>` to configure SecurityTokenValidators.

First register the JWT bearer and options

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            ...
        }).AddJwtBearer(AuthenticateScheme, options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ...
            };
        });
```

Then register a custom implementation of `IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>`

```
    services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, CustomJwtBearerOptionsPostConfigureOptions>();
```

And register a custom implementation of `ISecurityTokenValidator`

```
    services.AddSingleton<MyCustomSecurityTokenValidator>();
```

CustomJwtBearerOptionsPostConfigureOptions could look something like:

```
public class CustomJwtBearerOptionsPostConfigureOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
{
    private readonly MyCustomSecurityTokenValidator _tokenValidator; //example dependancy

    public CustomJwtBearerOptionsPostConfigureOptions(MyCustomSecurityTokenValidator tokenValidator)
    {
        _tokenValidator = tokenValidator;
    }

    public void PostConfigure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Clear();
        options.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(_tokenValidator);
    }
}
```

Now options.SecurityTokenValidators is configured by `CustomJwtBearerOptionsPostConfigureOptions` which is instantiated by dependency injection and can pass on the relevant decencies.

Comment: This is the only solution to this problem I've found so far, and it's neat. Wish it had more visibility in SO. Thanks.

Comment: After trying a ton of different dead-ends, this ended up the only thing that really worked well without going off-the-deep-end custom.  Confirmed working in .net5.0

Comment: I never knew about `IPostConfigureOptions`! Works perfectly fine :)

Comment: I used "ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, CustomJwtBearerOptionsPostConfigureOptions>();" instead of "    services.AddSingleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, CustomJwtBearerOptionsPostConfigureOptions>();
"