# In net core use a service within your own class and call the class using new class()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, token

I have created a class to validate my own token. Within this class I need to use a service, which I have previously added in the `startup.cs` with `services.AddScoped`. how can I do it ?

```
x.SecurityTokenValidators.Add(new DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler());
```

Inside the DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler class I need to use a service.

```
public class DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler : JwtSecurityTokenHandler, ISecurityTokenValidator
    {
        public SecurityKey GetKeyForClaimedId(string claimedId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal cp = new ClaimsPrincipal();
            validatedToken = null;
            try
            {
                cp = base.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
            } catch (Exception) {}

            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461714/12431728

Answer (score 1):

Use dependency injection in the constructor of the class

```
public class DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler : JwtSecurityTokenHandler, ISecurityTokenValidator
    {
        private readonly YourService _service
        public DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler(YourService service){
             _service = service
        }
        public SecurityKey GetKeyForClaimedId(string claimedId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal cp = new ClaimsPrincipal();
            validatedToken = null;
            try
            {
                cp = base.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
            } catch (Exception) {}

            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: no, because then I can't do new DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler() because constructor expects a service

Comment: @vidgarga, you should be injecting your DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler too, and not call its constructor directly using new. So DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler should be a service too.

Comment: Like Polyfun said ! However if you do not want to follow trough with this pattern you can just instantiate the service in the validationhandler class or pass it when calling `new DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler()` . I would highly recommend the proper injecting pattern tho !

Comment: @Polyfun Can you write a little example?

Comment: @vidgarga As DynamicKeyJwtValidationHandler implements ISecurityTokenValidator, then it should probably be added as a  ISecurityTokenValidator service. This post might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138849/how-to-correctly-get-dependent-scoped-services-from-isecuritytokenvalidator.