# .Net Core Dependency Injection inject out of constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I need to inject out of constructor, everything I declared in Setup.

Ho can I do it ? How can I inject services out of constructor ? 
Something like Injector service in Angular 2.

**INJECT SERVICES WITHOUT CONSTRUCTOR IN CONTROLLERS**

something like this

```
    public class ControllerBase : Controller
    {
        protected IRepository<Test> _test;
        protected IRepository<Test1> _test1;
        protected IRepository<Test2> _test2;

        public ControllerBase(INJECTOR injector)
        {
            _test = injector.inject(IRepository<Test>);
            _test1 = injector.inject(IRepository<Test1>);
            _test2 = injector.inject(IRepository<Test2>);
        }
    }

    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        public SomeController(INJECTOR injector)
            : base(injector)
        {

        }
    }
```

**THANKS FOR ANSWER @Rick van den Bosch**

**FOR THOSE WHO STILL CAN'T GET WHAT I WANTED:**

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected IRepository<Test> _test;
    protected IRepository<Test1> _test1;
    protected IRepository<Test2> _test2;

    public ControllerBase(IServiceProvider injector)
    {
        _test = injector.GetService<IRepository<Test>>();
        _test1 = injector.GetService<IRepository<Test1>>();
        _test2 = injector.GetService<IRepository<Test2>>();
    }
}

public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public SomeController(IServiceProvider injector)
        : base(injector)
    {
        //HERE I HAVE ALL 3 REPO NOW WITHOUT EXTRA LINES
    }
}
public class SomeController1 : ControllerBase
{
    public SomeController1(IServiceProvider injector)
        : base(injector)
    {
        //HERE I HAVE ALL 3 REPO NOW WITHOUT EXTRA LINES
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's question here?

Comment: Ho can I do it ? How can I inject services out of constructor ?

Comment: Have look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Comment: I know how DI works and how to register services, but it can be injected only in Constructors ... I need injection out of it.

Comment: I think middleware is fit into your requirement.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware.

Comment: no not middleware it's about injection I need to inject services WITHOUT CONSTRUCTOR IN CONTROLLERS

Comment: What do you mean with 'injection out'? At least a code sample would be useful to understand what your try to achieve.

Comment: Actually, you can inject via controller action method parameters. Just add `[FromServices]` in front of it.

Comment: thx juunas actually I need something like that but as variable, I am writing base controller and I want to inject default services without declaring them in constructor

Comment: @ITTeam Is that what you are looking for?
Here is the way to get the service provider from a controller 
without dependency injection.
"return this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IObject>();"
Unfortunatly I do not know if it is working from a constructor

Comment: @Lenny32 yep I got an answer but your answer is the same thx anyway.
IServiceProvider is all what I was looking for ))

Comment: Your example seem to use a service locator. You probably want to use ctor injection. Here's a link where you can read a bit about dependency injection and inversion of control in asp.net core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection

Comment: Actuall the pattern you show is not favoring composition over inheritance.  The code is saying "My controllers are repositories for test" when in fact they should only direct traffic to the true repositories for test.  Create models and use strong type binding instead.  Call the method in the model/viewmodel that does what you want from the controller.  Don't implement the DAL in the controller.

Comment: @JohnPeters check updated question I added answer I got

Comment: Unfreeze a question, please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inject the service as a parameter to the action method. This is done by marking the parameter with the attribute `[FromServices]`.

This looks something like this:

```
public IActionResult About([FromServices] IDateProvider dateProvider)
{
    ViewData["Message"] = $"Current date is {dateProvider.CurrentDate}";

    return View();
}
```

If you're looking for default services in a BaseController: you could go about that several ways:

**1. Still use a constructor**
This would look something like this:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController(IDateProvider dateProvider) : base(dateProvider)
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
public class BaseController
{
    protected IDateProvider _dateProvider;

    protected BaseController(IDateProvider dateProvider)
    {
        _dateProvider = dateProvider;
    }
}
```

This way the IDateProvider is available to both the BaseController and all inheriting Controllers.

**2. Resolve services manually**
This way you resolve the service manually. This could be in the BaseController, and only when you need them (lazy). For more info, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459670/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di).

For simplicity and readability I would probably choose the constructor one.

Comment: THANK YOU I NEEDED "2. Resolve services manually" IServiceProvider for resolving services