# .net core resolve dependency manually anywhere in the code

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Do you know how to manually resolve dependencies in **.net core**?
Something like

```
DependencyResolver.Resolve<ISomeService>()
```

**UPDATE**
I'm in a class that was not injected, I want to resolve it from the inside, rather than pass variables all over the place

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461714/3606250

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving instances with ASP.NET Core DI from within ConfigureServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459670/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di-from-within-configureservices)

Comment: Just be aware that you're creating a maintenance nightmare, as you can no longer trust the dependencies injected via the constructor to be *all* the dependencies. It will invariably lead to test harnesses that have to set up every service for every test, just because you lost control over which services are needed.

Answer (score 10):

Add your dependency in `ConfigureServices` as below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    //AddSingleton or AddTransient based on your requirements
    services.AddTransient<ISomeService, ConcreteService>();
}
```

In your controller or anywhere, add `IServiceProvider` in the constructor like below:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

...

public class HomeController
{
  ...
  public HomeController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
      var service = serviceProvider.GetService<ISomeService>();
  }
}
```

@Shazam, Here are some notes or suggestions based on your comment:

- If you can not inject because you might not have a constructor in this class, I woud suggest to add a paramter to your function and pass the resolved dependency from outside
- Another Idea is to add a static property and initialize its value in `ConfigureServices`

For Example:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static ISomeService MyServiceObj { set; get; }
    ....
}
```

In your `ConfigureServices`

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
        services.AddTransient<ISomeService, ConcreteService>();
        MyClass.MyServiceObj = services.GetService<ISomeService>();
    }
```

Hope this helps, please rate my answer or leave me a comment if you still in doubt how to do it

Comment: At design time you should know which dependencies your controller would have, inject IServiceProvider seems a bad idea, I'd inject only the service I know I will need...

Comment: @Juan I did it in this way based on his question giving him the choice to manually inject what he needs but it seems he doesn't have constructor in his class, thanks though for your note

Comment: @Shazam If you can not inject I woud suggest to add a paramter to your function and pass the resolved dependency from outside

Comment: Another Idea is to add a static method and initialize its value after resolve in ConfigureServices

Comment: @msoliman can you please add more details on the last comments? Thanks

Comment: That could do the job, you expose a property, MyDependency, and form the class that instantiate the class that need that dependency you might inject, resolve and set that Dependency to your problematic class.

Comment: What if you don't have any controllers in your project?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get scoped objects in a singleton object (like a BackgroundService), then serviceProvider.GetService method will raise an error stating this.
The solution is getting IServiceProvider during construction then when needed (in this case ExecuteAsync) a new scope should be created and all needed objects should be created in this scope.

```
public class MyService:BackgroundService 
{
  private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
  public MyService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
  }

  protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
  {
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
      var services = scope.ServiceProvider;            
      var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<MyService>>();
      logger?.LogInformation("MyService: ExecuteAsync");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  }
}
```