# Method injection in extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration

I have an extension method that takes in IHtmlHelper, like this :

```
public static HtmlString HelpContext(this IHtmlHelper helper)
{
    return "";
}
```

This function is then called from a Razor page.

I have my settings loaded in my startup, and it's ready to access via dependency injection. How would I go about this, without creating a static settings class? Is it possible to do method injection here, without having to inject the settings from the page on every call?

Comment: You may resolve the dependency inside the method using IServiceProvider, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50664743/net-core-resolve-dependency-manually-anywhere-in-the-code)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213803/use-dependency-injection-in-static-class

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325438/how-to-inject-dependency-to-static-class/52327577#52327577

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the static nature of the code being accessed, a service locator approach would need to be applied.

Resolve the desired type via the `IHtmlHelper.ViewContext`, which has access to the `HttpContext`. Allowing access to the `IServiceProvider` via the `HttpContext.RequestServices`

```
public static HtmlString HelpContext(this IHtmlHelper helper) {

    IServiceProvider services = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;

    var x = services.GetRequiredService<IMyType>();

    //...
    
}
```