# How to instantiate an object with a reference to another object that depends on DI ASP.NET core 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller's constructor in which I want to instantiate an object that gets access to the repository via dependency injection.

like this:

ContactController.cs: I get an error because I don't pass an IContactRepository

```
private ContactOperationsFacade contactOperator;

ContactController(){
    contactOperator = new ContactOperationsFacade(//I want to use DI here);
}
```

ContactOperationsFacade.cs:

```
private readonly IContactRepository contactRepository;

public ContactOperationsFacade(IContactRepository contactRepositor){
    this.contactRepository = contactRepository;
}
```

How can I instantiate this ContactOperationsFacade object in the controller's constructor still using DI for the repository?

Comment: Just inject `IContactRepository` into the controller and use it when you new up the facade.

Comment: is that the only way? I don't wanna have a dependency on the IContactRepository in my controller if possible

Comment: then register `ContactOperationsFacade` with IoC container and inject it instead, or use service locator but it's an anti-pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459670/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di and basically what @JSteward says below

Comment: Well you could inject whatever DI container you're using. But why can't you inject the `ContactOperationsFacade` instead of newing it up?

Comment: You *already* have a dependency on it. If it's necessary for your controller to do what it needs to do, then its a dependency. Newing it up inside the controller itself, simply hides the fact that the dependency is there, whereas making it required in the constructor properly advertises the dependency. If you want to use DI (and you should), you need to use DI *all the way*.

Comment: Sorry. I actually misread the comment. You do not need the controller to have a dependency on `IContactRespository`, but it does have a dependency on `ContactOperationsFascade`. Therefore, it should be injected into you constructor, rather than newing it up in the constructor.

Comment: I have many similar classes like ContactOperationsFacade and I don't wanna just inject all of them. I'm trying to have code that's easy to unit test (by making my methods not have any external dependencies, only primitive types) without abusing DI

Comment: @ChrisPratt should all the dependencies of controllers be injected?

Comment: *All* dependencies should be injected. So, yes, dependencies for controllers apply as well.

Comment: @ChrisPratt so you never new up objects in your code? always using DI?

Comment: Yep. I mean it doesn't mean you never use the `new` keyword again. There's plenty of things you'll new up, but mostly things like entity classes, view models, etc - things that are inherently transient in nature, don't have dependencies of their own, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net core you can do DI chaining as long as scopes allow it. So if A depends on B and the controller wants A you just add both A and B to the di container (ConfigureServices part of your code) and the container will figure it out.

Read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 1):

`ContactController` should follow [The Explicit Dependencies Principle](http://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

> Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects they need in order to function correctly.

Also classes should depend on abstractions and not coupled to concretions.

So assuming something like

```
public class ContactOperationsFacade: IContactOperationsFacade { //<-Note interface/contract

    private readonly IContactRepository contactRepository;

    public ContactOperationsFacade(IContactRepository contactRepositor){
        this.contactRepository = contactRepository;
    }

    //...
}
```

The controller should depend on the abstraction that the facade is derived from

```
public class ContactController: Controller {

    private readonly IContactOperationsFacade contactOperator;

    public ContactController(IContactOperationsFacade contactOperator){
        this.contactOperator = contactOperator;
    }

    //...

}
```

And assumes that all the interfaces and implementations are registered with the DI container.

```
services.AddScoped<IContactOperationsFacade, ContactOperationsFacade>();
```

once all dependencies are registered the service provider should resolve them when activating the controller.

Comment: I can inject a IContactRepository into my controller without any trouble, so. Why can't I inject a IContactRepository into my IContactOperationsFacade just as easly? I have many similar classes like ContactOperationsFacade and I don't wanna just inject all of them. I'm trying to have code that's easy to unit test (by making my methods not have any external dependencies, only primitive types) without abusing DI @Nkosi