# how to use redis cache in authorization filter?

Tags: filter, .net-core, stackexchange.redis

I want to store my credential in redis cache for authentication. For that I created the filter. But I could not use(inject) the IDistributedCache in filter.

```
public class Authorization : AuthorizeAttribute,IAuthorizationFilter
{
    IDistributedCache distributedCache;
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
    {
        //Authentication

        bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.Filters.Any(item => item is IAllowAnonymousFilter);
        if (skipAuthorization)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {

            string token = distributedCache.GetString("TokenValue");
            if (token == null)
            {
                // unauthorized!
                filterContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

If I generate constructor for above class and inject the IDistributedCache in constructor then I got an error while using that filter

So is there any another way to use redis cache in filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can generate a constructor and IDistributedCache as a parameter

Then you can register filter for an action like this:  `[TypeFilter(typeof(Authorization))]`

Code sample:

```
[HttpGet]
[TypeFilter(typeof(AuthorizationFilterAttribute))]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Comment: if you want to use DI in the pipeline I think you can call GetService<T> from your filter or delegating handler.  Then you don't have to decorate each method / class.

Comment: But if you are writing a custom Attribute like OP, so how can you inject IServiceProvider?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459670/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di

Comment: Here is a attribute class and he want to use  on action method. How to register if we dont use TypeFilter

Comment: The ASP.Net pipeline has many places where you can add code once and process all requests.  Delegating handlers, route attributes in the routing table, classes, model binders, etc.