# ASP.NET Core dependency injection - How to create instances?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In Startup:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>()
```

Controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSomething()
{
    Helper helper = new Helper(new MyService()); // works but looking better solution
    return Ok("");
}
```

Helper class:

```
public class Helper
{
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public Helper(IMyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public Helper()
    {
         this.myService = ?;
    }
}
```

I want to instantiate Helper class **without** inject the dependency manually with **new MyService()**.
The MyService() class should be the class in startup.
I also want to place the the Helper class in another assembly.

I see some code with

```
var service = (IFooService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMyService));
```

but i don't know how to get a serviceProvider instance without injecting it to the helper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving instances with ASP.NET Core DI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459670/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di)

Comment: https://medium.com/@chrisverwijs/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-ninject-for-dependency-injection-in-c-68a125bd7fa4

Comment: Then register helper and inject that to the controller. The container will inject relevant dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Add the helper to the container

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>()
services.AddScoped<Helper>(sp => new Helper(sp.GetRequiredService<IMyService>()));
```

And explicitly inject it into the controller

```
public class MyController: Controller {
    private readonly Helper helper;

    public MyController(Helper helper) {
        this.helper = helper;
    }    

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetSomething() {
        //...use helper 

        return Ok("");
    }

    //...
}
```

Ideally the helper should be derived from an abstraction as well

```
public class Helper : IHelper {
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public Helper(IMyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    //...
}
```

And added accordingly to the container

```
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>()
services.AddScoped<IHelper, Helper>();
```

to avoid the controller having tight coupling to concretions *(implementation concerns)*.

```
public class MyController: Controller {
    private readonly IHelper helper;

    public MyController(IHelper helper) {
        this.helper = helper;
    }    

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetSomething() {
        //...use helper 

        return Ok("");
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: `services.AddScoped<Helper>(sp => new Helper(sp.GetRequiredService<IMyService>()));` could just be `services.AddScoped<Helper>();`. No need to manually grab the dependency.

Answer (score 2):

A way to properly resolve the service via DI:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSomething([FromServices] IMyService myService)
{
    Helper helper = new Helper(myService);
    return Ok("");
}
```

Or you inject it via ctor and use it in the method.

Comment: it is not what i'm looking for. i updated my question a bit

Comment: I think you want to work around the di system which is probably a bad practice