# Specify custom IModelBinderProvider without new instance of IServiceProvider?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code in my `Startup` class, which uses a custom instance of `IModelBinderProvider`. Most input formatters require a `ILogger` instance, so I need to have an `ILoggerFactory`, and for that I want to use the configured one, which logs to specified destinations at specified verbosity. I'm grabbing the `ILoggerFactory` from a newly built `IServiceProvider`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
    
        services.AddMvcCore(
            options =>
            {
                ...
            
                var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                var loggerFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();

                options.ModelBinderProviders.Clear();
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Add(
                    new MyCustomBinderProvider(options.InputFormatters, loggerFactory)
                );
                
                ...
            }
        );
        
        ...
    }
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following warning:

```
Startup.cs(62, 43): [ASP0000] Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an
                    additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such
                    as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.
```

I took a look on this question: [Resolving instances with ASP.NET Core DI from within ConfigureServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459670/resolving-instances-with-asp-net-core-di-from-within-configureservices). However, my code is a lambda of `AddMvcCore`, which is configuring the `options` object. In other words, by the time the `Configure` is called, the MVC options are already defined.

Is there a way of doing the right thing here, i.e. prevent an extraneous instance of `IServiceProvider`?

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi. My custom binding provider is inspired by `BodyModelBinderProvider`, which takes an `ILoggerFactory` as input. In fact, there is already an instance of the `BodyModelBinderProvider`, the reason for which I have to call `Clear`. If ASP.NET Core are able to resolve the logger factory early, I think I should be able to do the same...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to inject services at the time configuring an options. The first way is by using an `OptionsBuilder<TOptions>` which can be obtained by using the extension method `IServiceCollection.AddOptions`, like this:

```
services.AddOptions<MvcOptions>()
         //first arg is always of TOptions, 
         //injectable dependencies start from the second arg
        .Configure((MvcOptions o, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) => {
                       o.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0,
                          new MyCustomBinderProvider(o.InputFormatters, loggerFactory)
                       );
                   });
```

The second way is by implementing an `IConfigureOptions<TOptions>` (or `IPostConfigureOptions<TOptions>`), like this:

```
public class ConfigureMvcOptions : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    public ConfigureMvcOptions(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }
    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0,
                  new MyCustomBinderProvider(options.InputFormatters, _loggerFactory)
               );
    }
}

//then configure it like this:
services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureMvcOptions>();
```

The first way is convenient because you don't have to create a separate class for implementation of `IConfigureOptions<Options>` but it has a limited number of injectable dependencies. The second way allows you to inject as many as you want and suitable for a large amount of configuring code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build the ServiceProvider to resolve the ILoggerFactory to pass it as a parameter.

Inside of your MyCustomBinderProvider you have access to resolve the ILoggerFactory, I think you should have something like this

```
public class MyCustomBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(CustomDto))
        {
            var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            return new MyCustomBinder(logger);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```