# How to set CookieExpiration Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to set CookieExpiration value from DB, however, I'm getting an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'EMS.Services.Interfaces.ISettingsService' while attempting to activate 'EMS.Startup'.'
```

This is the value from DB:

```
_settingsService.GetTheSettings().CookieExpirationPeriod
```

Startup:

```
public ISettingsService _settingsService;
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ISettingsService settingsService)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    _settingsService = settingsService;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Connection to DB
    services.AddDbContext<EMSDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));

    // Services for Sign in - Signout - Access Denied
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Auth/SignIn";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/SignOut";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Auth/AccessDenied";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(_settingsService.GetTheSettings().CookieExpirationPeriod);
    });
```

Comment: You can't inject a service into startup like that.  This is why your seeing and error only ConfigureServices will configure the service and you can access them later on

Comment: @AliK is right and  a simple solution is to register class as implemented services BEFORE using them

Comment: This question's accepted answer covers your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461714/2590680