# Instantiating objects with .NET Core's DI container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm using an `IServiceCollection` to create a list of required services for my objects. Now I want to instantiate an object and have the DI container resolve the dependencies for that object

**Example**

```
// In my services config.
services
    .AddTransient<IMyService, MyServiceImpl>();

// the object I want to create.
class SomeObject
{
    public SomeObject(IMyService service)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How to I get the DI container to create an object of type `SomeObject`, with the dependecies injected? *(presumably this is what it does for controllers?)*

**Note:** I do not want to store `SomeObject` in the services collection, I just want to be able to do something like this...

```
SomeObject obj = startup.ServiceProvider.Resolve<SomeObject>();
```

... Rationale: I don't have to add all of my controllers to the service container, so I don't see why I would have to add `SomeObject` to it either!?

Comment: Where/how you you want to create the object?

Comment: @Nkosi In the Main method of a console app...something like SomeObject x = startup.ServiceProvider.ResolveDependenciesFor<SomeObject>();

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863981/how-to-resolve-instance-inside-configureservices-in-asp-net-core

Comment: relevant article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707534.aspx

Comment: Use a service provider

Comment: In order to resolve an object, the service collection needs to be aware of how  to resolve it.

Comment: @Nkosi how does it know how to resolve any controller when I don't explicitly add them?

Comment: `Rationale: I don't have to add all of my controllers to the service container, so I don't see why I would have to add SomeObject to it either` The framework is doing that for you. it is using a convention and registers all controllers for you

Comment: You can create somethign like that yourself. eg. a custom attribute or interface that tags your custom classes and create an extension method that uses reflection to search for your classes and add them to the service collection.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As stated in the comments to the marked answer, you can use `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` method. This **functionality already exists** in .NET Core (since version 1.0, I believe).

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.activatorutilities.createinstance

Answer (score 6):

It's a little rough, but this works

```
public static class ServiceProviderExtensions
    {
        public static TResult CreateInstance<TResult>(this IServiceProvider provider) where TResult : class
        {
            ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(TResult).GetConstructors()[0];

            if(constructor != null)
            {
                object[] args = constructor
                    .GetParameters()
                    .Select(o => o.ParameterType)
                    .Select(o => provider.GetService(o))
                    .ToArray();

                return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TResult), args) as TResult;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is this using the `IServiceProvider` to instantiate the object (with all dependencies injected)?

Comment: @alexw .Select(o => provider.GetService(o))

Comment: @alexw basic principle, provided there is one constructor, iterate over it's parameter types, resovle them using the service provider and then create an instance using the results.

Comment: Uhh, shouldn't functionality like this already exist in the base framework? I don't want to be reinventing the wheel with this.

Comment: @flodin It's been a long time since I wrote this, but yes I think this functionality does already exist. The DI stuff baked into .NET Core implements the Service Locator pattern. This should lead you in the right direction... https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-di-deep-dive

Comment: I have sent 30 minutes to find again this answer to vote it up. Tnx. This solved my problem with DI and Activator.CreateInstance constructor parameters.

Comment: @series0ne That link does not describe how to get .net to resolve dependencies using Activator.CreateInstance

Comment: but how do I call this CreateInstance extension ... this doesn;t work :
IMyCar car = ServiceProvider.CreateInstance<IMyCar>();

Comment: @kahoona I would avoid using this implementation now. As stated, it's a little rough, and the built-in .NET Core DI stuff will do a better job (see the accepted answer).

Comment: oke but in the .NET Core way they say it's : var instance = (IPipe)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(serviceProvider, pipeType); . But then you still need a ServiceProvider object :-(. I can't understand why they made it so difficult to just instantiate a class with DI in a self written class.

Answer (score 0):

Extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T BuildObject<T>(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider, params object[] parameters)
        => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(serviceProvider, parameters);
}
```

Usage:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    var ss = HttpContext.RequestServices.BuildObject<SomeService>();
}
```