# ASP.NET Core Model Binding Error Messages Localization in ASP.NET CORE 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-localization

In ASP.NET CORE 1.1 it was possible to localize model binding error messages using a resource file and configure its options to set message accessors for ModelBindingMessageProvider in the Startup.cs like

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var F = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizerFactory>();
    var L = F.Create("ModelBindingMessages", null);
    options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.ValueIsInvalidAccessor =
        (x) => L["The value '{0}' is invalid."];
```

as shown here: [ASP.NET Core Model Binding Error Messages Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828570/asp-net-core-model-binding-error-messages-localization) and here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/05/09/aspnetcore-mvc-error-message/

In ASP.NET CORE 2.0 I receive an error message on all of the ModelBindingMessageProvider's properties

```
options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.ValueIsInvalidAccessor
```

is readonly

How can these messages be localized in ASP.NET CORE 2.0

Comment: I added VS 2017 ASP.NET Core 2.0  sample to the [repository](https://github.com/r-aghaei/AspNetCoreLocalizationSample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into this. These setters were replaced with methods such as `SetValueIsInvalidAccessor`, the change is described here: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/240

Comment: Thank you for your fast help!

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET Core 2.0, model binding message provider properties have got read only, but a setter method for each property has been added.

So if you follow the example of my [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40828570/3110834), to set `ValueIsInvalidAccessor`, you should use `SetValueIsInvalidAccessor` method this way:

```
options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor (
    (x) => L["The value '{0}' is invalid."]);
```

#### Sample Project

I added the sample project for ASP.NET CORE 2.0 in the following repository:

- [r-aghaei/AspNetCoreLocalizationSample](https://github.com/r-aghaei/AspNetCoreLocalizationSample)

#### Default Error Messages:

- *MissingBindRequiredValueAccessor*: A value for the '{0}' property was not provided.
- *MissingKeyOrValueAccessor*: A value is required.
- *MissingRequestBodyRequiredValueAccessor*: A non-empty request body is required.
- *ValueMustNotBeNullAccessor*: The value '{0}' is invalid.
- *AttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor*: The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.
- *NonPropertyAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor*: The value '{0}' is not valid.
- *UnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor*: The supplied value is invalid for {0}.
- *NonPropertyUnknownValueIsInvalidAccessor*: The supplied value is invalid.
- *ValueIsInvalidAccessor*: The value '{0}' is invalid.
- *ValueMustBeANumberAccessor*: The field {0} must be a number.
- *NonPropertyValueMustBeANumberAccessor*: The field must be a number.

Comment: The "A value is required." translation does not work for me, all other do. If I change your model from int Id to string Id and put a [Required] above, I always receive the English error instead of the translation. Does it work on your side?

Comment: It's not the problem of default model binder error messages.  It's because of `Required` attribute. When you use data annotations validation attributes, you need to localize them as well.

Comment: To solve the problem, do the same thing that I've done for `StringLength` attribute. Add `[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is Required.")]` above the property. Then in `Models.SampleModel.fa.resx` add `{0} is Required.` having value `فیلد {0} الزامی است.`.

Comment: Thank you. I new this option, but was talking about the default error message using [Required] only, without any Errormessage in brackets. This one seems to be hard to get translated.

Comment: You're welcome :) This is the way that error message localization for data annotations work. I believe it's not hard to translate `{0} is Required.` ;)

Comment: Just curious - where do the default messages come from? I searched entire GitHub but found only resource names, such as `Resources.FormatModelBinding_MissingBindRequiredMember` but I could not find the specific text strings anywhere.

Comment: @JustAMartin Take a look at xml comment (summary) of properties in [Resources.Designer.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Properties/Resources.Designer.cs). This file is auto-generated from [Resources.Resx](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Resources.resx), take a look at data tags.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this configuration for localize mvc core error messages :

```
public class SomeMvcOptionsSetup : Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions>
{
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer _resourceLocalizer;

    public SomeMvcOptionsSetup()
    {
    }

    public SomeMvcOptionsSetup(Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizerFactory stringLocalizerFactory)
    {
        _resourceLocalizer = stringLocalizerFactory.Create(baseName:"ResourceClassName",location:"ResourceNameSpace");
    }

    public void Configure(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueIsInvalidAccessor((x) =>
        {
            if (_resourceLocalizer == null)
            {
                return "Custom Error Message";
            }

            return _resourceLocalizer["Specific Resource Key In Resource File"]; 
        });

        options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor((x) =>
        {
            if (_resourceLocalizer == null)
            {
                return "Value Can not be null....";
            }
            return _resourceLocalizer["ResourceKeyValueCanNotBeNull"];
        });

  .
  .
  .


    }
}
```

Then, add the following to your Startup.ConfigureServices(...) method:

```
 services.TryAddEnumerable(
ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>,SomeMvcOptionsSetup >());
```

Please see this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6698)