# ASP.NET MVC Localizing or Changing Default Model Binding Error Messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, localization, model-binding

**How to change the language for "The value 'some value' is not valid for 'some property'" validation  error?**

Can anyone help? I want to translate the error in the picture to Russian [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tahT2.png). I read much sites, try to use `RegularExpression`, but it doesn't help
may be I don't correctly understand how to do that?

I need only translate the error, not need to change the culture.

*In web.config:*

```
<globalization culture="en" uiCulture="en" />
```

My entity with data annotations attributes:

```
public class Player
{
    /* Some other properties */

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Укажите среднее количество блокшотов")]
    [Range(0, 10.0, ErrorMessage = "Недопустимое значение, до 10")]
    public float BlockPerGame { get; set; }

    /* Some other properties */
}
```

*My View:*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)    
    <div class="box-form">

    /* Some other properties */

    <div class="text-style-roboto form-group">
        <label>Среднее количество блокшотов</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BlockPerGame, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BlockPerGame)
    </div>

    /* Some other properties */

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="button button-create" id="button-create">Добавить</button>

        @Html.ActionLink("Отмена", "Index", null, new { @class = "button button-cancel", id = "button-cancel" })
    </div>
</div>
}
```

*And my Controller:*

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    /*Some other methods*/
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Player player, string ChoosingTeam)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (ChoosingTeam != string.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    player.TeamId = int.Parse(ChoosingTeam);
                    await repository.SavePlayerAsync(player);
                    TempData["message"] = string.Format("Игрок {0} {1} сохранены", player.Name, player.Surname);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = new SelectList(repository.Teams, "Id ", "Name");
        ViewBag.ChoosingTeamName = list;
        return View(player);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are entering an invalid float number (you use ',' istead of '.' as a separator). What if you use string as data type with [RegularExpression] instead of float? In this way you can add your custom error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enter an invalid value for a property, if model binder cannot bind that value to the property, the model binder sets an error message for that property. It's different from data-annotations model validation. It's in fact model binder validation error.

**Localizing or Changing Default Model Binding Error Messages**

Model binding error messages are different from model validation messages. To customize or localize them, you need to create a global resource and register it in `Application_Start` for `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey`.

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Go to *Solution Explorer*
2. Right click on project → *Add* → *ASP.NET Folder* → Choose *App_GlobalResources*
3. Right click on *App_GlobalResources* → Choose *Add New Item*
4. Choose *Resource File* and set the name to *ErrorMessages.resx*
5. In the resource fields, add the following keys and values and save the file:

   - `PropertyValueInvalid`: `The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.`
   - `PropertyValueRequired:` `A value is required.`

***Note:*** If you want to just customize the messages, you don't need any language-specific resource, just write custom messages in the `ErrorMessages.resx` and skip next step.

6. If you want localization, for each culture, copy the resource file and paste it in the same folder and rename it to *ErrorMessages.xx-XX.resx*. Instead of `xx-XX` use the culture identifier, for example `fa-IR` for Persian language 
   and enter translation for those messages, for example for *ErrorMessages.fa-IR.resx*:

   - `PropertyValueInvalid`: `مقدار '{0}' برای '{1}' معتبر نمی باشد.`
   - `PropertyValueRequired:` `وارد کردن مقدار الزامی است.`
7. Open Global.asax and in `Application_Start`, paste the code:

   ```
   DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "ErrorMessages";
   ```

**ASP.NET CORE**

For ASP.NET Core read this post: [ASP.NET Core Model Binding Error Messages Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40828570/3110834).

Comment: doesn't translate
1) i create ErrorMasseges.ru-RU.resx
2)Name: PropertyValueInvalid ; Value:Значение '{0}' записано не верно в  {1}.
Name: PropertyValueRequired; Value : Значение пропущено
3) in global.asax   add  DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "ErrorMessages"; 

i have the same english error

i try fa-IR it doesn't translate

Comment: Because the culture of your application is still neutral culture. For you, since I see you are using Russian error messages even for neutral culture, just use Russian messages in `ErrorMasseges.resx`. Forget about the `ErrorMasseges.ru-RU.resx`.

Comment: Make sure you have created the resource file in `App_GlobalResources` and follow my previous comment. As far as I see you are not using localization for validation attributes, so a single resource file for neutral culture would be enough.

Comment: My mistake sorry
that's working, thank you so much!!! really help!
i delete ru-Ru and it worked