# ASP.Net Core - How use custom 'ModelBindingMessageProvider'

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, localization, startup

I have a simple ASP.Net Core app which uses razor. The user forms are generated by model and data annotation attributes. The error message of wrong input values are English by default. I knew that I can translate default message with help of '**ModelBindingMessageProvider**'.

Below you can find a working way (in Startup.cs) by update the '**DefaultModelBindingMessageProvider**':

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(o =>
    {
        // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828570/asp-net-core-model-binding-error-messages-localization
        o.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(u => "My custom validation error message");
    });
}
```

I would prefer not to configure the translation directly in the startup.cs. One way to do that is using a custom class which inherits from 'ModelBindingMessageProvider'.

```cs
public class MyModelBindingMessageProvider : ModelBindingMessageProvider
{
    public override Func<string, string> ValueMustNotBeNullAccessor => o => "My custom validation error message";
}
```

Here is my question:

1. Where register My own class?
2. Is this a good way? What is best practice at the moment?

*(the real app uses string resources of course)*

Comment: This might help a little? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/05/09/aspnetcore-mvc-error-message/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but that doc does not help. He describes before the breaking changes was done (see: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/240).

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I agree with you. It seems better than putting the translations in the Startup class.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like it's not possible to provide a custom implementation of `ModelBindingMessageProvider` in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

The [constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e81033e094d4663ffd227bb4aed30b76b0631e6d/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/MvcOptions.cs#L48) of `MvcOptions` sets the `ModelBindingMessageProvider` property to an instance of `DefaultModelBindingMessageProvider`.

```
ModelBindingMessageProvider = new DefaultModelBindingMessageProvider();
```

And the [property](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e81033e094d4663ffd227bb4aed30b76b0631e6d/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/MvcOptions.cs#L168) itself has no setter and is not of type `ModelBindingMessageProvider`.

```
public DefaultModelBindingMessageProvider ModelBindingMessageProvider { get; }
```

**tl;dr** Even though the option of having an own implementation would make sense here, you have to configure the messages in the `Startup` class.