# How to localize default validation message for value-type (ushort) properties if value is out of the type boundaries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, data-annotations, asp.net-core-localization

I have some web form where user should enter the port number. Of course the best type for the port number is ushort. I use RangeAttribute to validate the port number and some error message.

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
[Display(Name = "Port")]
[Range(1, ushort.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Invalid value")]
public ushort Port { get; set; }
```

The localization works correct only if I enter values from 0 to 65535. So there is only one incorrect case - zero value. But if I try to save empty value, enter negative values or values greater than 65535, I get completely another error message (`The value '-1' is not valid for Port.`) and I don't know how to localize it.

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: This is what I need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828570/asp-net-core-model-binding-error-messages-localization

Answer (score 0):

The 'easy' way is to use `short` (or a greater signed type) instead `ushort`, the model binding process ocurs after model validation, therefore, since the value -1 is incompatible with `ushort` the process will stop there and your custom error will never be read.

The hard way is write your own model validator:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `int` and custom validation attribute like

```
public class PortPolicy : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if ((int)value >= 1 && (int)value <= 65535)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid value");
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The field is required")]
[Display(Name = "Port")]
[PortPolicy]
public int Port { get; set; }
```

Comment: but I am still able to use ushort type, right? And just catch the parse exception.

Comment: Could you explain clearly what do you want to do in your case?What do you mean `localize` the error message here? Where do you see the message?

Comment: see my comment on the main question.