# How to localize standard error messages of validation attributes in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, validationattribute, asp.net-core-localization

How to localize standard error messages of validation attributes in ASP.NET Core (v2.2)? For Example, **[Required]** attribute has this error message "**The xxx field is required.**"; **[EmailAddress]** has "**The xxx field is not a valid e-mail address.**"; **[Compare]** has "**'xxx' and 'yyy' do not match.**" and so on. In our project we use not English language and I want to find a way how to translate standard error messages without writing them directly in every attribute of every data-model class

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to localize the error messages but not to build a multi-language site, you may try this: *(the message strings may be in your language.)*

1. Add a custom `IValidationMetadataProvider` :

```
    public class MyModelMetadataProvider : IValidationMetadataProvider
    {
        public void CreateValidationMetadata(ValidationMetadataProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException();
            }
            var validators = context.ValidationMetadata.ValidatorMetadata;

            // add [Required] for value-types (int/DateTime etc)
            // to set ErrorMessage before asp.net does it
            var theType = context.Key.ModelType;
            var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(theType);

            if (theType.IsValueType &&
                underlyingType == null && // not nullable type
                validators.Where(m => m.GetType() == typeof(RequiredAttribute)).Count() == 0)
            {
                validators.Add(new RequiredAttribute());
            }
            foreach (var obj in validators)
            {
                if (!(obj is ValidationAttribute attribute))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                fillErrorMessage<RequiredAttribute>(attribute, 
                    "You must fill in '{0}'.");
                fillErrorMessage<MinLengthAttribute>(attribute, 
                    "Min length of '{0}' is {1}.");
                fillErrorMessage<MaxLengthAttribute>(attribute, 
                    "Max length of '{0}' is {1}.");
                fillErrorMessage<EmailAddressAttribute>(attribute, 
                    "Invalid email address.", true);
                // other attributes like RangeAttribute, CompareAttribute, etc
            }
        }
        private void fillErrorMessage<T>(object attribute, string errorMessage, 
            bool forceOverriding = false) 
            where T : ValidationAttribute
        {
            if (attribute is T validationAttribute)
            {
                if (forceOverriding ||
                    (validationAttribute.ErrorMessage == null 
                    && validationAttribute.ErrorMessageResourceName == null))
                {
                    validationAttribute.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

2. add some lines in `Startup.cs` :

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddMvcOptions(m => {
                    m.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new MyModelMetadataProvider());

                    m.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustBeANumberAccessor(
                        fieldName => string.Format("'{0}' must be a valid number.", fieldName));
                    // you may check the document of `DefaultModelBindingMessageProvider`
                    // and add more if needed

                })
                ;
        }
```

see [the document of DefaultModelBindingMessageProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.metadata.defaultmodelbindingmessageprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

If you can read in Japanese, see [this article](https://www.nextdoorwith.info/wp/se/imptech/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-validation-default-japanese-message/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine in ASP.NET Core 7.0.  BTW, defining a custom EmailAddressAttribute error message won't have any effect in all major browsers, because ASP.NET Core adds the type="email" to the input, which triggers the browser's validation, and if it doesn't pass, the browser displays its own error message (in the browser's current language) and the form isn't submitted

Answer (score 1):

This is spelled out in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#dataannotations-localization). You can do either:

1. Use the `ResourcePath` option on the attribute.

   ```
   [Required(ResourcePath = "Resources")]
   ```

   Then, you'd add the localized message to `Resources/Namespace.To.MyClass.[lang].resx`.
2. Use one resource file for all classes:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddMvc()
           .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
               options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                   factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
           });
   }
   ```

Comment: looks like this approach expects ErrorMessage parameter for all attributes in all models to be translated. I want to avoid it