# dotnet invalid json body client message

Tags: c#, .net

I have asp.net web api application. When I try to send request with invalid Json to my api, the response is bad request.
how can i change response client message?
I try `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` and `ModelBindingMessageProvider` in
[ASP.NET Core Model Binding Error Messages Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828570)

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] ForTestJson request)
    {
        //some operation after validation
    }

}

public class ForTestJson
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateTimeOffset { get; set; }
}
```

the request is like below with invalid type of `Id` and `DateTimeOffset`

```json
{
  "id": "aaa",
  "name": "string",
  "dateTimeOffset": "bbb"
}
```

the response is

```json
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-a3ab5818c8cdc45073d5f5c8941887e9-3fcff0b267c68057-00",
  "errors": {
    "request": [
      "The request field is required."
    ],
    "$.id": [
      "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int64. Path: $.id | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 13."
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to change "The JSON value could not be converted to ..." to another message

Comment: Can't you share the code which does the validation and returns the response?

Comment: I Create new web API project and I don't use any custom validator. the response generated by default asp.net validator.

Answer (score 0):

Your request body cannot be deserialized to an instance of `ForTestJson` because the data types of the `id` and `dateTimeOffset` properties in the request don't match those of the corresponding properties in the `ForTestJson` class.

If you want to return a different error message, you could change the signature of your `Post` method to accept a `string` rather than a `ForTestJson` instance, and then write your own code in the `Post` method to attempt to deserialize the string from JSON to a `ForTestJson` instance, catch any exceptions thrown during deserialization, interpret the exceptions and build your own error message from them.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the JSON errors using `AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages`:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(o => o.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = false)
```

This changes the message to a more generic ""The input was not valid.".

For the general case, there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this except to inspect the error dictionary directly. You can do that using `AddProblemDetails` and casting the details to `HttpValidationProblemDetails` to get to the error dictionary:

```
services.AddProblemDetails(options => {
    options.CustomizeProblemDetails = context => {
        var details = context.ProblemDetails as HttpValidationProblemDetails;
        if (details == null) return;
        foreach (var key in details.Errors.Keys) {
            if (details.Errors[key].Any(v => v.Contains("The JSON value could not be converted"))) {
                details.Errors[key] = new[] { "Your message here" };
            }
        }
    };
});
```