# Asp.net core resource localization for data annotations doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

The Problem with this class:

```
public class ApplicationVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ApplicantFullName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfCreation { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateOfSent { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfDays { get; set; }

    public ApplicationTypeVM Type { get; set; }
    public ApplicationStatusVM Status { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "StatedDates required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^((?:^|\s*)\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})*$", ErrorMessage = "StatedDates invalid")]
    public string StatedDates { get; set; }

    [UIHint("CoordinatorEditor")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Coordinator required")]
    public string CoordinatorFullName { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Data annotations error messages don't localize. I inherit this class for other view models which are used on UI. For example, this one:

```
public class RemoteWorkingApplicationVM : ApplicationVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "WorkingPlan required")]
    public List<ActivityVM> WorkingPlan { get; } = new List<ActivityVM>();
}
```

Other localization is working. I think the problem is with inheritance. What do you think?

Comment: maybe you are missing ```.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()``` after .AddRazorPages() or .AddMvc()

Comment: I think this answer may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828570/asp-net-core-model-binding-error-messages-localization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thoughts were correct, the problem was with the inheritance. In my case, I needed to add entries for data annotation messages in resources for all supertype view models.