# How to localize 'The X field is required' native error in .NET API?

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I'm building custom validation response from my API with localization. I need to localize default error messages for variables on model binding when requesting API. I localized almost everything, but I still get `The X field is required` in English.

I used solution from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64681729/13448281) and it works well with .NET 7, however this options configurator misses message for `The X field is required`.

I also found solution with adding `[Required]` attribute and overriding its message, but application is in advanced state, so this would take a lot of time.

Comment: why not using fluentvalidation https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

Answer (score 1):

When using FluentValidation you can define the rules as follows:
`RuleFor(v => v.Item) .NotNull() .WithMessage("'Item' cannot be null.");`

Provide the localization inside the WithMessage().

Comment: similar to `[Required]`, it would make me refactor whole solution, this is what I try to avoid

Answer (score 0):

why not using fluentvalidation docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

Comment: I am using FluentValidation, but you still need to provide translations for base errors