# access dbcontext in custom Newtonsoft JsonConverter class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I created an JsonConverter for mapping children entitys to list of ids in json
for example `childrens:[1,2,3]`

```
public class IdsJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{ 
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType==typeof(ICollection);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //problem convert ids back to entities because i can not get db context here so I unable to get the tracked entities from context
        return existingValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        IEnumerable collection = (IEnumerable)value;
        List<long> ids = new List<long>();
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            dynamic itemCollection = (dynamic)item;
            ids.Add(itemCollection.ID);
        }
        //successful convert to list of ids 
        serializer.Serialize(writer, ids);
    }
}
```

the problem is i can not get db context in ReadJson() 
the dbcontext is added to the services container using the Scoped lifetime

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped((_) => new MyDatabase(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

this is how I use IdsJsonConverter

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IdsJsonConverter))] 
    public virtual ICollection<TAG> TAGs { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you save your IoC container as a static variable in some place. Then in your ReadJson, get that container and resolve your DbContext instance.

Comment: using static dbcontext seems not recommend in mvc core

Comment: I mean the IoC Container, not the static dbcontext. I am not sure about MVC CORE, but using AutoFac, you should have a container, and you can store that container somewhere to use.

Comment: Your question maybe answer in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863981/how-to-resolve-instance-inside-configureservices-in-asp-net-core

Comment: This seems like a bad architectural decision. Why would a JSON serializer have anything to do with fetching data from a data store?

Comment: because this Converter was convert entities to an simple number list, it need to convert back to tracked entities by reading database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call below code in your ConfigureServices

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Then assign this serviceProvider as a static variable in some place. Eg: `App.ServiceProvider`.

In your ReadJson

```
App.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDatabase>();
```

You need Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection for this to work.

Comment: Is you mean store serviceProvider in somewhere static and I get my services by calling serviceProvider.GetService<CmpDatabase>();?

Comment: I am able to get the DbContext now, this way is simple and elegant.