# How to add model to PredictionEnginePool in middleware (ML.NET)?

Tags: ml.net, asp.net-core-middleware

I'm using ML.NET in an ASP.NET Core application, and I am using the following code in `Startup`:

```
var builder = services.AddPredictionEnginePool<Foo, Bar>();

if (File.Exists("model.zip"))
{
    builder.FromFile(String.Empty, "model.zip", true);
}
```

If **model.zip** doesn't exist, I create it later in the middleware. How do I add it to  the `PredictionEnginePool` that is injected?

There are no options to load a model via `PredictionEnginePool`, and instantiating or injecting a `PredictionEnginePoolBuilder` isn't an option as it requires `IServiceCollection` (so must be configured during `Startup.ConfigureServices`).

The only option I can see at the moment is to set a flag if the file doesn't exist at startup, and then restart the service after **model.zip** is created in the middleware later on (using `IApplicationLifetime.StopApplication`), but I really don't like this as an option.

Comment: I've also noticed this limitation of the `PredictionEnginePool`. The only workaround I can think of, if you can't always guarantee the file exists, is perhaps to run an Azure Function or scheduled tasks that checks if it doesn't exist and moves gets it from Azure Storage or somewhere else.

Comment: @Jon Yes, but the reason it wouldn't exist during `Startup.ConfigureServices` is if it hasn't been created yet. My app will then create it later in the middleware, which is of course _after_ `Startup.ConfigureServices` has run. At that point, I then need access to the model via `PredictionEnginePool`, which means I need to programmatically restart the application so that **model.zip** can be read in during startup. I suppose there's one other way to do this, and that's to split my API in two - one that's responsible for creating the model, and one that uses it (has the `PredictionEnginePool`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PredictionEnginePool` is designed in such a way that you can write your own `ModelLoader` implementation. Out of the box, `Microsoft.Extensions.ML` has 2 loaders, File and Uri. When those don't meet your needs, you can drop down and write your own.

See https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/pull/560 which changes one of the dotnet/machine-learning samples to use an "in-memory" model loader, it doesn't get the model from a file or a Uri. You can follow the same pattern and write whatever code you need to get your model.

```cs
    public class InMemoryModelLoader : ModelLoader
    {
        private readonly ITransformer _model;

        public InMemoryModelLoader(ITransformer model)
        {
            _model = model;
        }

        public override ITransformer GetModel() => _model;

        public override IChangeToken GetReloadToken() =>
            // This IChangeToken will never notify a change.
            new CancellationChangeToken(CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

And then in Startup.cs

```cs
            services.AddPredictionEnginePool<ImageInputData, ImageLabelPredictions>();
            services.AddOptions<PredictionEnginePoolOptions<ImageInputData, ImageLabelPredictions>>()
                .Configure(options =>
                {
                    options.ModelLoader = new InMemoryModelLoader(_mlnetModel);
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and apologies for the delay in replying. The changes in the PR you mentioned rely on `TensorFlowModelConfigurator.Model` being set from a file path during `Startup` anyway. So that in itself doesn't solve my problem where I create the model later on in the middleware, after `Startup` has already passed. So, are you suggesting that I would achieve this by passing my middleware service (obtained with `services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService` in `ConfigureServices` for instance) to the custom `ModelLoader` and then getting the model from it in the call to `GetModel`?

Comment: I'm saying that you can follow this pattern to write a class that inherits from `ModelLoader` and do whatever you need in that class to get access to the model. So if you need a reference to some middleware service in order to get the model, then you can write a `MyMiddlewareServiceLoader : ModelLoader` that knows about that middleware service.

Comment: I tried using a custom `ModelBuilder` but found I'm unable to access middleware services during `Startup.ConfigureServices`, and `AddPredictionEnginePool` doesn't offer an overload that accepts an implementation factory where I would normally be able to access `IServiceProvider` as I would with `AddAddSingleton`, `AddScoped` and `AddTransient`. Using the method I mentioned before (`ServiceProvider.BuildServiceProvider`) results in a warning that an additional copy of singleton services would be created. I've fixed this and raise a PR [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/pull/4393).