# How can I add Option object as service?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

In my ASP.NET Core application configuration usually doesn't change. So I want to create a typed Options object in `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` and add that object as a singleton to the services using `services.AddSingleton(typeof(IOptions), configuration.Get<Options>())`.

But ASP.NET Core doesn't allow to add additional parameters to the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method.

So the following isn't possible:

```cs
public interface IOptions { ... }
public class Options : IOptions { ... }

...

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
  services
    .AddSingleton(typeof(IOptions), configuration.Get<Options>())
    .AddControllers();
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this (i.e. adding an Option object, configured by ASP.NET configuration services, to the services collection)?

Comment: How is “options / configuration” created..? Why is this extra parameter required? Remember IoC has not kicked in yet.

Comment: See above sample code: The `Options` class is a local class. Configuration is supposed to be taken from any configuration provider (e.g. `appsettings.json`).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461831/2864740 (build a SP) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton (using a function to generate singleton value), perhaps. I’m not sure if the SC has (or is guaranteed to have) the IConfiguration registered at that point, hence the potential need to defer.

Comment: D'oh! ... Thank you for linking. I didn't see these yesterday. Today, with a fresh mind, I even noticed that `IConfiguration` is a member of `Startup`, fed by DI. So I don't need to do anything - it's already there. I'll add a corresponding solution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was close at hand and I overlooked it:

`IConfiguration` is available as a member field in Startup, so it's already available and no need to provide it again as additional argument:

```cs
public class Startup
{
  private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;



  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => _configuration = configuration;



  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container for dependency injection.
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services
      .AddSingleton<Options>(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<Options>())
      .AddControllers();
  }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Options options)
  {
    Context.ConnectionString = options.DbConStr;
  }
}
```