# How to get an object of my class with options (that mapped via services.Configure<>) immediately?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration

I'm going to use JWT Bearer Authorization for my site. But the configuration of this takes a lot of place in the `Startup.cs`. I decided that I need to create something like extension method in a static class to make my `Startup.cs` more readable. Here is the code of this extension method:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddAuthenticationWithBearer(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.Configure<AuthOptions>(configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions"));

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddScoped<IJwtService, JwtService>();

        // Can I use already mapped AuthOptions instead of this ???
        var jwtConfigurationSection = configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions");
        
        services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = jwtConfigurationSection.GetValue<bool>("ValidateIssuer"),
                ValidIssuer = jwtConfigurationSection.GetValue<string>("ValidIssuer"),
                ValidateAudience = jwtConfigurationSection.GetValue<bool>("ValidateAudience"),
                ValidAudience = jwtConfigurationSection.GetValue<string>("ValidAudience"),
                ValidateLifetime = jwtConfigurationSection.GetValue<bool>("ValidateLifetime"),
                IssuerSigningKey =
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["AuthJwtSecret"])),
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = jwtConfigurationSection.GetValue<bool>("ValidateIssuerSigningKey"),
            };
        });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        return services;
    }
```

My main problem under the comment. I know about convenient mechanism with  `services.Configure<AuthOptions>(configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions"));`. So, section 'JwtOptions' from `appsettings.json` is mapped on `AuthOptions` class. But I have no idea how I can use this here! As you can see, I have the call of `configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions");` here, but I don't like it. I would like to use mapped `AuthOptions` class. I think you understand my reasons: 1) If I will change `appsettings.json`- I have only one place where I should to think about changes. It's `AuthOptions`. Next - IDE will highlight the rest. 2) I want to have only one way to getting configurations from `appsettings.json`. And I like the way with mapped class like `AuthOptions`.

Comment: already asked many times, for example  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863981/how-to-resolve-instance-inside-configureservices-in-asp-net-core

Comment: there are two options:
1 - build service provider and resolve instanse (as you want).
2 - bind GetSection to some variable, use that variable to register options and use for registration. (I would suggest this approach)

Comment: @EgorPopov why you prefer the second?

Comment: Please, check link, that I have provided above, there is common question and already has answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for the `Bind` method.

```
AuthOptions authOptions= new AuthOptions();
configuration.GetSection("JwtOptions").Bind(authOptions);
TokenValidationParameters tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
   ValidateIssuer = authOptions.ValidateIssuer,
   ValidIssuer = authOptions.ValidIssuer
   // etc.
}

services
   .Configure<AuthOptions>(authOptions);
services
   .AddAuthentication()
   .AddJwtBearer(options =>
   {
      options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
   };
```

Comment: And as an alternative to your answer I can build service provider, right? Which approach is better and why? What do you think?