# Inject AddSqlServer with another service

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Is it possible to resolve an instance of `ISettingsService` from the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup(.cs) - webapplication?

I've implemented a `SettingsService` which is able to retrieve the database connectionstring from an external source (secure credentials store). Within the ConfigureServices I need an instance of the `ISettingsService` in order to get the connectionstring and pass it to the `services.AddSqlServer<MyDbContext>(connectionstring)` method.

While creating the instance (`using var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider(); var settings = provider.GetService<ISettingsProvider>()`;) Visual Studio displays the next error:

[image]

Another developer posted a similar question on StackOverflow and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278027/1974344) provides a solution in case of AddSingleton/ AddTransient. What is the correct way to apply it on the AddSqlServer call? Or could you provide another solution to avoid the warning/ error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intellisense comment for `.AddSqlServer` actually says to use `.AddDbContext` if you need more control, and that's certainly the correct option.

If you refer to the source code [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/7433fe6ea77f2cffe437ff9c1b088bb2420235f9/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Extensions/SqlServerServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L58-L73), you can see that all `.AddSqlServer` is actually doing is calling `.AddDbContext` and configuring the options accordingly. We can therefore write our own solution like this:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>((serviceProvider, options) => {
    var settings = serviceProvider.GetService<ISettingsProvider>();
    // I don't know what methods your ISettingsProvider makes available
    // so adjust accordingly
    string connectionString = settings.GetSetting("connectionString");
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
```

Of course you can make other changes to the options here, and `.UseSqlServer` can also take a `Action<SqlServerDbContextOptionsBuilder>` (`options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, opts => opts.EnableRetryOnFailure())`, etc.) to further configure it.